# How to fetch a flv link and play it on Vitamio

Tags: android, fetch, flv, vitamio

I want to know a way to fetch flv links and play it using vitamio library. So far i can play embedded youtube videos by fetching youtube links.

Sample code on fetching youtube videos

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int possition, long arg3) {

                ProgramEpisode listCatogory = (ProgramEpisode) innerList
                        .get(possition);
                if (listCatogory.getEpisodeVideo().equals("null")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Video is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {

                    if (YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(
                            InnerTeleActivity.this).equals(
                            YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS)) {

                        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
                                InnerTeleActivity.this, API_KEY,
                                listCatogory.getEpisodeVideo());
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri
                                .parse("ytv://"
                                        + listCatogory.getEpisodeVideo()),
                                InnerTeleActivity.this,
                                OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(lVideoIntent);
                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you play youtube flv link in android webview?

Comment: it's not uploaded to youtube. What i have is uploaded on a server.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417143/playing-flv-android